# (Ctrl + Z = previous step) what about next step?

Tags: android-studio

I by mistake clicked on ctrl + z and I removed all previous steps (codes) I made, now I wanna retrieve it again , what should I do ?
with note that I've searched for this matter and I couldn't get the soulution.

Comment: Isn't it Ctrl + Y?

Comment: But it's offline choice for me @P.Juni

Comment: try `ctrl+shift+Z` or `ctrl+Y`

Comment: ctrl + y will remove a line, if it's really that kind of problem it is ctrl + shift + z then

Comment: ctrl+shift+Z is offline choice for me @Andre

Comment: How about to check in the Menu `Edit` to look for `undo` and `redo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly for you are looking for but

```
CTRL + SHIFT + Z
```

or

```
Right Click the file -> Local History -> Show history
```